# VBA Excel copy & paste & define image inside the function

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to copy image from one worksheet and spread it across a multitude of created worksheets with specified parameters (location and size).
Unfortunately, I can't do it.

With the following code:

```
 Function CreateStandardSheet(wkb As Workbook, SheetName As String) As Worksheet
 Set CreateStandardSheet = wkb.Sheets.Add(After:=wkb.Sheets(wkb.Sheets.Count))
 With CreateStandardSheet
 Worksheets("Frontsheet").Shapes("SLogo").Copy
 With .Shapes("SLogo")
 .PasteSpecial
 .Top = 300
 .Left = 550
 .ShapeRange.Width = 250
 End With

 End With
```

and I am getting this error:

**Object doesn't support this property or method**

How could I define the parameters of the image inside of the function?

Comment: A `Shape` doesn't have a `PasteSpecial` method.

Comment: When changed to .Paste still doesn't work - the same error

Comment: Instead of guessing what methods an object has, it might be better to check the documentation or the object browser first.

Comment: A `Shape` also doesn't have a `ShapeRange` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Shape` doesn't have a `PasteSpecial` method.

```
Function CreateStandardSheet(wkb As Workbook, SheetName As String) As Worksheet
    Set CreateStandardSheet = wkb.Sheets.Add(After:=wkb.Sheets(wkb.Sheets.Count))
    Worksheets("Frontsheet").Shapes("SLogo").Copy
    CreateStandardSheet.Paste

    With CreateStandardSheet.Shapes("SLogo")
        .Top = 300
        .Left = 550
        .Width = 250
    End With
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity - Is Copy/Paste the most efficient way of replicating the image?  It seems like exporting the image to a temp location (store the location in a Global so that it can be accessed repeatedly) and then inserting the image from that location would be less resource intensive.

Comment: @FrankBall - honestly not sure but somewhat smells to me of premature optimization.

Comment: It's the result of 20 years as .NET developer  - EVERYTHING gets optimized...

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next adapted code, too:

```
Function CreateStandardSheet(wkb As Workbook, SheetName As String) As Worksheet
 Set CreateStandardSheet = wkb.Sheets.Add(After:=wkb.Sheets(wkb.Sheets.count))
 Dim sh As Shape
  With CreateStandardSheet
    wkb.Worksheets("Frontsheet").Shapes("SLogo").Copy
    .Paste
    Set sh = .Shapes(.Shapes.count) 'sometimes the pasted shape does not keep the original one name
                                    'and it is good to use this method for sheets also keeping other shapes
    With sh
        .top = 300
        .left = 550
        .width = 250
    End With
  End With
 End Function
```

You can test it using:

```
Sub trestCreateStandardSheet()
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Set ws = CreateStandardSheet(ThisWorkbook, "MyNewSheet")
   
   Debug.Print ws.Shapes.count, ws.Shapes(ws.Shapes.count).name
End Sub
```